# Removing stop words that are not in NLTK library in python

Tags: python, preprocessor

I have been trying to remove stopwords from a csv file that are not found in the NLTK library, but when I generate the new dataframe an addition section that is supposed to be "cleaned", I still see some of those words in there, and I am not sure how to remove them. I am not sure what is wrong with my code but here it is:

````
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus  
import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
print(len(stop_words))
stop_words.extend(["consist", "feature", "site", "mound", "medium", "density", "enclosure"])

def clean_review(review_text):
   # review_text = re.sub(r'http\S+','',review_text)
    review_text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',str(review_text))
    review_text = str(review_text).lower()
    review_text = word_tokenize(review_text)
    review_text = [word for word in review_text if word not in stop_words]
    #review_text = [stemmer.stem(i) for i in review_text]
    review_text = [lemma.lemmatize(word=w, pos='v') for w in review_text]
    review_text = [i for i in review_text if len(i) > 2]
    review_text = ' '.join(review_text)
    return review_text

filename['New_Column']=filename['Column'].apply(clean_review)```
````

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the contents of `filename['Column]'` and respective `filename['New_Column']`?

Answer (score 1):

You are lemmatizing the text after removing the stopwords, which is OK sometimes.

But, you might have words that after lemmatizing it would be in your stopwords list

See the example

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

>>> lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("sites"))
site
>>>
```

At first, your script wouldn't remove `sites`, but after lemmatizing, it should.